# Destroying jQuery Flot Graph

Tags: jquery, flot

What is the correct way to destroy a jQuery flot graph in a way that will clean up all event handlers and not result in a memory leak?

It seems flot is leaving behind some zombies (aka Detached Dom Trees)

Comment: `$.plot('#yourFlotDiv', {}, {});` read it somewhere. Don't exactly remember where.

Answer (score 7):

If you read the API docs, there is a shutdown method that cleans up for you

```
shutdown()

Cleans up any event handlers Flot has currently registered. This
is used internally.
```

eg.

```
var plot = $.plot($("#yourDiv"), options)

plot.shutdown()
```

Answer (score 4):

For people who come here in the future, there is now a `destroy` function that calls shutdown and removes the canvas element. It's undocumented in the API for some reason, but is available in the code:

```
var flot = $("#FlotDiv").data('plot')
if (flot) // If it's destroyed, then data('plot') will be undefined
    flot.destroy();
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want to remove event handlers then try `jquery off` method.

for to clear flot graph.  you can empty the div.

```
$('#yourFlotDiv').empty();
```

Comment: What arguments should be passed to jQuery.off()?

Comment: @thecountofzero $("#yourFlotDiv").off("yourEventHandlerTORemove"); for more info see this http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: I am talking about making sure flot cleans up all of its event handlers and deletes all of the DOM elements that it created.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the flot Graph

```
var placeholder = $("#FlotDiv");
placeholder.unbind(); //Remove a previously-attached event handler from the elements.
placeholder.empty();
```

Also in case you wish to unbind specific event this is the way to go :

```
$( "#foo").unbind( "click" );
```

For more info check [this](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) out.